# How to choose a scalar metric to monitor parallel processing's performance?

Tags: multithreading

Suppose we are talking about a program that has 100 threads, each thread will process its own data partition (part0 part1 part2, ..., part99).

Now we need to monitor the whole program's performance. We can introduce: end-to-end time metric, sum of all data bytes metric, etc.

So far things are manageable and easy.

During processing, suppose each thread needs to spend some time to wait for something, and each thread will do such wait() for unknown amount of times. The thread keeps processing data between two wait().

The question is: how to define a metric to measure the impact of these wait() to the whole program's performance?

Several strawman proposals include:

1. calculate every thread's all wait() time, and then calculate the max_for_all_thread(wait_time). Meaning, the max of all threads' wait time.
2. almost the same to option-1, but we calculate the sum of all threads' wait time.
3. write down all wait()'s start and end timestamp, and concatenate and report all of them.

None of these options is satisfactory enough. For the "report-all" option above, it takes too much space to report this metric; For the "sum" option above, we cannot say a big metric value indicates a problem because all of those wait() might happen at the same time, then we misdiagnosed the performance bottleneck; For the "max" option above, we cannot say a small metric value indicates no-problem because all of those wait() might happen at a different time, then we misdiagnosed the performance bottleneck again (similar for a big metric value).

So now the question I want help is: can we define a metric that is both: 1, takes small space (scalar value is the best here); 2, can help us answer the question: is wait() the performance bottleneck here?

Thanks.

Comment: The waiting time is a parallel time. You should really not mix that with wall clock time. The result is likely to be useless whatever the metric unless it is specifically designed to include the exact behaviour of the target threads (i.e. specific/intrusive). Regarding what your threads do (ie. dependencies), some waiting time can have a strong impact on the performance.

Comment: If you really want to mix both, then you should build a task graph, compute the dependencies (and the critical path), and simulate a scheduling of the graph without the waiting time. This is very complex to do (especially the scheduling part). Naive generic metrics are very likely to provide useless results.

Comment: Not mixing parallel/wall-clock timings means your metric is stuck to using the parallel time. AFAIK, the only one generic one consists in subtracting the (parallel) waiting time to the global parallel time (and divide it by the global parallel time to get a 0-1 ratio). It just tells you how much threads spent time doing computation or waiting.